# disable and enable onclick event based on condition

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$("[id^=column]").unbind('click',popup);
});

function popup()
{
    alert('gggg');
}

function enable()
{
    $("[id^=column]").bind('click',popup);
}
</script>

<a onclick="enable()">enable</a>
<table width="200" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr><td id="column1" onclick="popup('a')">1</td></tr>
<tr><td id="column2" onclick="popup('b')">2</td></tr>
<tr><td id="column3" onclick="popup('c')">3</td></tr>
<tr><td id="column4" onclick="popup('d')">4</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td></tr>
</table>
```

Hi,

I want to disable table TD onclick on page load once he click on enable link then only TD onclick will be enabled?how to acheive this?

Thanks

Comment: Your logic seems to fail, why bind an event which should be unbound on window load? Maybe following some check you didn't talk about

Answer (score 1):

Why not only bind the popup function when the enable link is clicked?

```
<script>
function popup()
{
    var $this_el = $(this);
    var param_1 = $this_el.attr("data-parameter-1");
    alert('Parameter is: ' + param_1);
}

// bind click event to td
function enable()
{
    $('.clickable').on('click', popup);
}

// bind click event to enable link
// using .one() will unbind itself after it is triggered once.
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#enabler').one('click', enable);
});
</script>

<a id="enabler">enable</a>
<table width="200" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr><td id="column1" class="clickable" data-parameter-1="a">1</td></tr>
<tr><td id="column2" class="clickable" data-parameter-1="b">2</td></tr>
<tr><td id="column3" class="clickable" data-parameter-1="c">3</td></tr>
<tr><td id="column4" class="clickable" data-parameter-1="d">4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ya, why? I don't get it too

Comment: what if user clicks on enable link 4-5 times

Comment: thanks that really works!!! you asked me to enable popup when link is clicked now i have edited my question.Here i have dynamic paramater passed in function

Comment: Probably best to use data attributes - see edited answer. Note that your question is now slightly outside of the scope of your original question so you should really ask a new one if you need further clarification. Please accept this answer if it helped you solve your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `onclick` attribute, [.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) removed only those handlers which are added by a [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#column1").removeAttr('onclick');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d8tbM/)

Comment: @downvoter Did I miss anything in terms of the error in OP's code.... I agree that the inlined handler should have been there in the first place... that said was there anything wrong in the solution

Answer (score 0):

The inline event handler within the HTML on the `a` tag can be removed.  This event handler can be assigned purely with Javascript.

Assign a callback to the click event handler for the `a` tag.  Inside this function, setup the click event handler on `#column1`.

**HTML**

```
<a>enable</a>
<table width="200" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr><td id="column1" onclick="popup()">1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("a").one("click",function(){
        $("#column1").click(function(){
            popup();
        });     
    });
});

function popup()
{
    alert('gggg');
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TCrR4/

Comment: what if user clicks on enable link 4-5 times

Answer (score 0):

Try this buddy..

I made some changes in your code..

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $("a").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("action"))
      {
        $("#column1").removeClass("action")
        $("#column1").bind("click",function(){  
        alert("hiii");
      $(this).unbind("click");}); 
       alert("binded");
      }
    else
     {
        $("#column1").addClass("action")
        $("#column1").unbind("click");
        alert("unbinded");
      }
 });
 });
```

Comment: what if user clicks on enable link 4-5 times

Comment: It will bind again and again if you want to unbind at the next click it can be simply achieved by adding and removing class.